# How to perform segue after current presentation is completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a situation in my app where I need to dismiss a modal view controller via unwind segue, then right after that present a different modal view controller. To do so, I am simply delaying the call to present the new view controller by 1.0 seconds. This may not work all the time, perhaps if it takes longer to dismiss for some reason, the second view controller won't be able to appear because a transition is occurring. I just ran into this situation, although it did work in this case. This was logged:

*Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!*

I am looking for a better solution. I wondered if it would be possible to throw up the new view controller after the first one is fully dismissed, via a callback, but there is no `performSegueWithIdentifier` that has a completion block.

**How can I dismiss a modal view controller then present a new one afterwards, always ensuring there will be no conflict?**

This is my current solution:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Unwind Segue" sender:self]; //dismiss modal or pushed VC

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [tabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show New VC" sender:self]; //present new modal VC
});
```

Comment: Why not present the new modal controller from the current one, rather than unwinding first? What is the purpose of unwinding then immediately presenting another one?

Comment: I unwind back to where the tab bar is visible, then perform the segue because that segue is only defined for the `tabBarController`. This is a complex app with many screens, and I didn't desire to create a segue to this view controller out of every single view controller. Additionally it is actually desired to go back to the "main page" in this scenario.

Comment: I think you should be able to call performSegue in the viewDidAppear method of the controller you're unwinding to. You could set a flag in the unwind method, and check that in viewDidAppear to know whether you should do the performSegue or not.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I will attempt that, thanks!

Comment: How about using `viewDidDisappear` of the view controller that's unwinding? As in, once it has disappeared, tell the parent view controller to perform the segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can also do is add a notification on the new controller's viewDidAppear function using NSNotificationCenter.  Then, you attach a listener to the notification and when you see the notification show up, you do your next transition.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"transitioned to new controller!" object:nil]];
}
```

elsewhere, just add this to listen to the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNotification:) name:@"transitioned to new controller!" object:nil];
```

Don't forget to stop listening after you receive your notification (unless you desire to remain observing) for this notification, otherwise you will continue observing all notifications throughout your application:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"transitioned to new controller!" object:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the use of notifications. I used this along with Eric Amorde's suggestion of using viewDidDisappear, and rdelmar's suggestion of using a bool to know whether or not to segue after dismissal. Thanks all!

Answer (score 10):

It took me awhile to figure this one out myself.  iOS 7 introduced the `transitionCoordinator` which is only present on a UIViewController during an animation.  In short, you must register your completion block in another thread on the main queue (which will run after the animation kicks off).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // ... prepare your for segue

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
         {
             // Segue animation complete
         }];
    });
}
```

Comment: *"you must register your completion block in another thread"*. It's not "another thread", it's run (later) on the (same) main thread.